# Character Limit on GetQuerySuggestions Sevice Method

Tags: search

The [GetQuerySuggestions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsearch.queryservice.getquerysuggestions%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method for the search autocomplete seems to truncate results longer than 128 characters. Is there anyway to remove this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be a limitation of the DB. The column where these are stored is of type `nvarchar(128)`. Not too much to be done.